# Memory leak with OpenCv 3.2.0 when in thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, c++11

On Win7, on msys2 with a mingw-64 toolchain (but the same happens on linux gcc), with OpenCv-3.2.0 (but it is the same with 3.1.0).

Here is the code that I tried to simplify as much as possible to show my problem:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include "opencv_detector.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>

/**
* Returns the current resident set size (physical memory use) measured in bytes
*/
inline size_t getCurrentRSS( )
{
  PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS info;
  GetProcessMemoryInfo( GetCurrentProcess( ), &info, sizeof(info) );
  return (size_t)info.WorkingSetSize;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  auto opencvDetector = new wl::ds::OpencvDetector();
  cv::Mat img = cv::imread("./test.png");
  int i = 0;
  long rss = getCurrentRSS();
  long rss_start = rss;
  long rss1 = rss;
  std::cout << std::setw(7) << "START " << rss <<std::endl;
  while(i++<1000) {
    // If I just call the function no memory leak
    //opencvDetector->process(img);
    // If I call the function in a thread, memory leak
    auto opencvDetectProfile = std::thread(&wl::ds::OpencvDetector::process, opencvDetector, img);
    opencvDetectProfile.join();

    rss1 = getCurrentRSS();
    if(rss!=rss1) {
      std::cout << std::setw(6) << i << " " << rss1 << " (" << std::setw(8) << (rss1-rss) << " / " << std::setw(7) << (rss1-rss_start) << ")" << std::endl;
      rss = rss1;
    }
  }
  std::cout << std::setw(7) << "STOP " << rss1 << " (" << std::setw(8) << (rss1-rss) << " / " << std::setw(7) << (rss1-rss_start) << ")" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

and here is the very simple openCvDetector class:

```
#ifndef WL_DS_OPENCVDETECTOR_H
#define WL_DS_OPENCVDETECTOR_H

#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

namespace wl {
namespace ds {


class OpencvDetector {
 private:
   cv::CascadeClassifier cascadeClassifier;
 public:
   OpencvDetector() { cascadeClassifier.load("haarcascade_frontalface.xml"); };
   void process(cv::Mat img) {
     cv::cvtColor(img, img, CV_BGR2GRAY);
     cv::equalizeHist(img, img);
     std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;
     cascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(img, faces, 1.05, 3, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE);
   };
};

} // wl
} // ds

#endif // WL_DS_OPENCVDETECTOR_H
```

If I call directly `opencvDetector->process(img);` the memory usage stabilizes rapidly:

```
START 18280448
     1 30892032 (12611584 / 12611584)
     2 30908416 (   16384 / 12627968)
     4 30928896 (   20480 / 12648448)
     5 30941184 (   12288 / 12660736)
     8 30945280 (    4096 / 12664832)
    11 30953472 (    8192 / 12673024)
    12 30957568 (    4096 / 12677120)
  STOP 30957568 (       0 / 12677120)
```

But if I run the threaded version (the member function of OpenCvDetector is called in a thread), the memory usage keeps growing:

```
START 18280448                      
    1 30965760 (12685312 / 12685312)
    2 30879744 (  -86016 / 12599296)
    3 30883840 (    4096 / 12603392)
    8 30916608 (   32768 / 12636160)
   10 31035392 (  118784 / 12754944)
   11 31047680 (   12288 / 12767232)
   12 30961664 (  -86016 / 12681216)
   14 30965760 (    4096 / 12685312)
   20 30969856 (    4096 / 12689408)
  120 31346688 (  376832 / 13066240)
  121 31084544 ( -262144 / 12804096)
  153 31088640 (    4096 / 12808192)
  213 31092736 (    4096 / 12812288)
  233 31096832 (    4096 / 12816384)
  248 31100928 (    4096 / 12820480)
  294 31105024 (    4096 / 12824576)
  335 31109120 (    4096 / 12828672)
  417 31113216 (    4096 / 12832768)
  499 31117312 (    4096 / 12836864)
  504 31121408 (    4096 / 12840960)
  540 31125504 (    4096 / 12845056)
  581 31129600 (    4096 / 12849152)
  665 31133696 (    4096 / 12853248)
  749 31137792 (    4096 / 12857344)
  781 31141888 (    4096 / 12861440)
  833 31145984 (    4096 / 12865536)
  848 31207424 (   61440 / 12926976)
 STOP 31207424 (       0 / 12926976)
```

I'm disappointed because I want to achieve a lot of OpenCv detections in a lot a threads, so what seems a little memory leak is rapidly becoming a huge waste of resources.
Any hint would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same `opencvDetector` in all of your threads, this can lead to undefined behavior. In your case it is causing the memory leak.

Try this way:

```
auto opencvDetector = new wl::ds::OpencvDetector();
auto opencvDetectProfile = std::thread(&wl::ds::OpencvDetector::process, opencvDetector, img);
opencvDetectProfile.join();
delete opencvDetector;
```

Comment: Hi Rama. Correct me If I'm wrong, there is no problem with the opencvdetector single instance itself, the problem is related to the use of a single instance of CascadeClassifier? I have to try that tomorrow morning but it would be annoying because loading a cascade is not a very light thing...

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the new avenue to explore!
Although, I dont understand how this could be a problem as I join the thread each time, but it's still interesting to know if that could be a problem.

Comment: Hello @Rama. After multiple other tests, it looks like, even if your solution does not fit my needs (as it would just drop performance instead of memory),  you're kind of right, one cant call detectMultiScale on the same cv::CascadeClassifier in multiple threads (notably stated here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4287).